# how to access virtual host set in vagrant

Tags: php, curl, vagrant, virtualhost

I am having debian vagrant. I have done virtual host configuration in its apache as servername `https:local-dev02.sitename.com.` And used in my windows machine host file `127.0.0.1 local-dev02.sitename.com`.

I can access my site in windows' browser as `https://local-dev02.sitename.com:8443/`.
But I am unable to do

```
ping https://local-dev02.sitename.com
OR 
curl https://local-dev02.sitename.com
OR 
wget https://local-dev02.sitename.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only possible to ping a hostname or IP address, but not an URL. So you need to put off the protocol like so

```
ping local-dev02.sitename.com
```

To reach your hosts via the hostnames, please add the IPs and hostnames to the `/etc/hosts` file.